# Flatten records into columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to flatten multiple records from a table as distinct columns in the result set. For ex:

```
select product_id, url from images where product_id = 1;

+-------------+-------------------------------+
| product_id  | url                           |
+-------------+-------------------------------+
|           1 | http://example.com/images/abc |
|           1 | http://example.com/images/def |
|           1 | http://example.com/images/ghi |
+-------------+-------------------------------+
```

I want the result set to have three columns something like this:

```
+-------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| product_id  | Image 1                         | Image 2                       | Image 3                       | 
+-------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|           1 | http://example.com/images/abc   | http://example.com/images/def | http://example.com/images/ghi |
+-------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

In case, we do not have three rows, I want the last columns to be null. For ex-

```
select product_id, url from images where product_id = 2;
+-------------+-------------------------------+
| product_id  | url                           |
+-------------+-------------------------------+
|           2 | http://example.com/images/abc |
|           2 | http://example.com/images/def |
+-------------+-------------------------------+
```

Then, the output should be:

```
+-------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| product_id  | Image 1                         | Image 2                       | Image 3                       | 
+-------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|           2 | http://example.com/images/abc   | http://example.com/images/def | NULL                          |
+-------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

In case of more than 3 rows, we can safely ignore more than 3 rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: MySQL Version: 5.6

Answer (score 2):

A correlated subquery might be the simplest approach:

```
select p.product_id,
       (select i.url
        from images i
        where i.product_id = p.product_id
        order by i.image_id
        limit 1 offset 0
       ) as url1,
       (select i.url
        from images i
        where i.product_id = p.product_id
        order by i.image_id
        limit 1 offset 1
       ) as url2,
       (select i.url
        from images i
        where i.product_id = p.product_id
        order by i.image_id
        limit 1 offset 2
       ) as url3
from products p;
```

This assumes you have a table called `products`.  If not, you can always use `(select distinct product_id from images) p`.

This also assumes you have an image id column in `images`.  If not, you can use `order by url`.

If you don't want to use the `products` table, you can do:

```
select p.product_id,
       (select i.url
        from images i
        where i.product_id = p.product_id
        order by i.image_id
        limit 1 offset 0
       ) as url1,
       (select i.url
        from images i
        where i.product_id = p.product_id
        order by i.image_id
        limit 1 offset 1
       ) as url2,
       (select i.url
        from images i
        where i.product_id = p.product_id
        order by i.image_id
        limit 1 offset 2
       ) as url3
from (select distinct product_id from images) p;
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the part of your answer where you have mentioned that there is no products table.

Comment: Swap `limit` and `offset`. I couldn't get them to work in SQLFiddle as `offset x limit x` but it did work with `limit x offset x`.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is pretty good at making things that should be easy much harder. This is still a PIVOT, but it's a little different in MySQL than T-SQL.

EDIT: We can replicate the `ROW_NUMBER()` functionality with the dynamic variables `@rn` to hold the row number and `@pid` to hold the previous row's product_ID, then `CROSS APPLY` that back to the `images` table. I use the `rn` value to correlate the `product_ID` records.

`Product_ID` 3 demonstrates that it will ignore any more than 3 image urls returned.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3647b2/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE images (product_id int, url varchar(50) ) ;
INSERT INTO images 
SELECT 1,'http://example.com/images/abc' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'http://example.com/images/def' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'http://example.com/images/ghi' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'http://example.com/images/abc' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'http://example.com/images/def' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'http://example.com/images/qrz' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'http://example.com/images/rzq' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'http://example.com/images/zqr' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'http://example.com/images/qqq' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'http://example.com/images/rrr' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'http://example.com/images/zzz'
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT s1.product_ID
  , max( CASE WHEN s1.rn = 1 THEN s1.url END ) AS Image1
  , max( CASE WHEN s1.rn = 2 THEN s1.url END ) AS Image2
  , max( CASE WHEN s1.rn = 3 THEN s1.url END ) AS Image3
FROM (
  SELECT t1.product_ID, t1.url
    , @rn:=CASE WHEN @pid=product_ID THEN @rn+1 ELSE 1 END AS rn
    , @pid:=product_ID AS pid
  FROM images t1, ( SELECT @rn:=0,@pid:='' ) AS t
  ORDER BY t1.product_ID
) s1
GROUP BY s1.product_ID
ORDER BY s1.product_ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3647b2/1/0)**:

```
| product_ID |                        Image1 |                        Image2 |                        Image3 |
|------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|
|          1 | http://example.com/images/abc | http://example.com/images/def | http://example.com/images/ghi |
|          2 | http://example.com/images/abc | http://example.com/images/def |                        (null) |
|          3 | http://example.com/images/rrr | http://example.com/images/qqq | http://example.com/images/zqr |
```

Answer (score 1):

This will sort out the records in url group by product_id. Then get the first three records per group_id.

```
select product_id,
       max(case when rank=1 then url end) as url_1,
       max(case when rank=2 then url end) as url_2,
       max(case when rank=3 then url end) as url_3
from (       
  select  a.product_id, 
        a.url,
        count(b.product_id)+1 as rank
  from  images a 
  left join images b 
  on a.product_id=b.product_id and a.url>b.url
  group by  a.product_id,
          a.url
   )  t
group by product_id
order by product_id;
```